# How to replace ionic footer elements' text contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'd want to replace the text `Check{{product.name}}` to `Check{{user}}` if a condition is true.

I spent hours, tried `hidden, display:none, .hide()` etc. but none of them worked..
I also tried to create another `<a>` block for `check{{user}}` and hide the block if the condition is not true, but it does not work as well....

Wondering if someone could please help! Thanks.

There is my code:

**html:**

```
<ion-footer-bar class="bar-positive" ng-if="loggedUser!=user.id" > 
    <a href="link" id="newtest"> check {{product.name}}</a> 
</ion-footer-bar>
```

**js:**

```
if (user_name !=''){ 
    //change Check{{product.name}}" to "Check{{uesr}}"
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<ion-footer-bar class="bar-positive" ng-if="loggedUser!=user.id" > 
<a href="link" id="newtest"> 
  <span ng-show="your_condition"> check {{product.name}} </span> 
  <span ng-show="!your_condition">Check{{uesr}}</span>
</a> 
</ion-footer-bar>
```

Comment: Hi Saurabh, thanks for answering. i added as below, but it only shows :Check{{uesr}} whether or not the condition is true...

  <span ng-show="user_name ==' ' "> check {{product.name}} </span> 
  <span ng-show="user_name !=' ' ">Check{{uesr}}</span>
&
  <span ng-show="!(user_name !=' ') "> check {{product.name}} </span> 
  <span ng-show="user_name !=' ' ">Check{{uesr}}</span>

Answer (score 0):

If it is just text your replacing, then it is pretty easy.

```
$('ion-footer-bar > a').html('Check{{user}}');
```

Comment: Hi Haze, thanks for your answer, I've put the code into my condition, but it does not work...

Comment: How about this, `$('a#newtest').html('Check{{user}}');`. Last resort, I dunno if that will work for you thou. :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your problem is within your controller. When ion-footer-bar is outside the content, the scope is not shared with the footer. Make sure you wrap your html with a `<div>` and define a controller there before do a conditioning logic in your view.

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">

    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
      <h1 class="title">Header</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>

    <ion-nav-view>
      <ion-content>
        Your content here
      </ion-content>
    </ion-nav-view>

    <ion-footer-bar class="bar-positive">
       <span  ng-if="loggedUser!=user.id"> 
           <a href="link" id="newtest"> check {{product.name}}</a> 
       </span>
        <span  ng-if="loggedUser==user.id"> 
           <a href="link" id="newtest"> Check{{user}}</a> 
       </span>
    </ion-footer-bar> 

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the first answer, you can also use

angular2 with `*ngIf = (condition)` inside of  or  to achieve the same results